# Auth0 Lock - Google oauth2 unable to get refresh_token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, auth0

I'm using Auth0 Lock with the `google-oauth2` connection and I need to get a `refresh_token` because I need to make API calls from the server-side when the user is offline.

I'm following their guide but it's not working, `refreshToken` is always `undefined`.

Using `http://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.7.2/lock.min.js`

```
this.lock = new Auth0Lock('...', 'xxx.eu.auth0.com', {
  initialScreen:'login',
  allowedConnections: ['google-oauth2'],
  allowSignUp: false,
  auth: {
    redirect: false,
    responseType: "token",
    params: {
      'access_type': 'offline',
      'approval_prompt': 'force',
    },
  },
  autoclose: true
});
```

Tried also with `params`
`'approval_prompt': 'force'` or `'prompt': 'select_account consent'`

Instructions here: https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/rules/google-refresh-token.md

Comment: Is `google-refresh-token` rule removed? I could not found the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rule is wrong. IdP `access_tokens` are available through the management API. See this endpoint: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/get_users_by_id

A special scope is required (`read:user_idp_tokens`).

This is because IdP tokens are sensitive artifacts, so Auth0 puts an extra layer of security to obtain them.

> You can of course call the API from a rule, but we'd likely advise against it and instead have your backend act on behalf of your (front-end) app.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly.
I have a SPA application that I want to connect to a backend in Node. 
On the SPA I'm using Lock and you are telling me that I need to use Management API (on the server I suppose) but I don't fully understand how I will be able to obtain the `refresh_token`. Is Auth0 saving that refresh_token somewhere for me to be retrieved after?

Comment: The refresh_token (Google one, that is) is retrieved after authentoication and stored as part of the User Profile in Auth0. To retrieve it, you use the endpoint I wrote about above. You can easily see this for yourself by logging in and then using the API explorer. The IdP (Google) tokens (both access_token and refresh_token) will be under the Identities data structure.

Comment: Now it's all clear, thank you Eugenio! And thanks for the great product that is Auth0!

Comment: There is a strange behaviour when calling the endpoint `GET /api/v2/users/{id}`, for example I make a call and I get an `access_token` with `expire_in: 3600`, then I wait 10 seconds and I call the endpoint again: I get the same `access_token` and again `expire_in:3600`, how is this possible?

Comment: The `expires_in` refers to the Google access_token from when it was obtained (essentially, the last time the user logged in). It means that if you try to use the token to call a Google API after that period of time, Google will reject it. Notice that is in "seconds".

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have it as `expiry_date` in Unix Timestamp? (Google does this). It would make developers life simpler since we don't have to manually calculate the expiry timestamp (that is what you want to use to compare against your current time)

Comment: Likely, but it is not what the standard says: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.2
I guess we could add that more handy property though.

Comment: I have tried to get user detail after logged in. But in the response, I only get the `access_token`. How I can get the `refresh_token` from the response?

Comment: @bountyhunter bear in mind some things have changed in the Auth0 API, I would suggest you post the code you are using so it's easier to help you :)